# Golang un-gzip from bytes.Reader

Tags: go

I have a file struct that holds a body which is just a `*bytes.Reader` I have two methods on the struct `Zip() error` and `UnZip() error`.  When I call `Zip` it should zip the file storing the zipped data in body and I should be able to call `UnZip` on the same file and store the unzipped data in the body.

The minimal example I have is below in the playground. https://play.golang.org/p/WmZtqtvnyN

I'm able to zip the file just fine and looks like it's doing what it's supposed to do; however, when I try and unzip the file I get `unexpected EOF`

I've been going at this for hours now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should close gzip writer before geting bytes from the underlying buffer.

```
func (f *File) Zip() error {
    buff := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    writer := gzip.NewWriter(buff)
    defer writer.Close()

    _, err := f.Body.WriteTo(writer)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    writer.Close() // I have added this line

    f.Body = bytes.NewReader(buff.Bytes())
    f.Name = fmt.Sprintf("%s.gz", f.Name)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://godoc.org/compress/gzip#NewReader) for `gzip.NewReader`, `If r does not also implement io.ByteReader, the decompressor may read more data than necessary from r.`

For  [bytes.Reader](https://godoc.org/bytes#Reader), `A Reader implements the io.Reader, io.ReaderAt, io.WriterTo, io.Seeker, io.ByteScanner, and io.RuneScanner interfaces by reading from a byte slice.`

The problem maybe lies in the fact that `bytes.Reader` does not implement `io.ByteReader`.

Comment: It actually does implement io.ByteReader because io.ByteScanner is a io.ByteReader too.